# Incorrect value in logic in output in comparing string. MacOS, Python

Tags: python, macos

I wrote code that compares browser's version on device and latest existed version of browser.

Here:

```
import requests
import subprocess


def get_last_version(browser_name):
    res = requests.get("https://vergrabber.kingu.pl/vergrabber.json")
    last_version = repr(res.json()['latest']['client'][browser_name]['version'])
    return last_version[2:-1]


def get_current_version(app_path):
    res = subprocess.Popen(
        'defaults read /Applications/' + app_path + '/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString',
        shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    current_version = res.read()
    return current_version


def compare_versions(browser_name, app_path):
    if get_last_version(browser_name) == get_current_version(app_path):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    get_last_version('Google Chrome')
    print get_last_version('Google Chrome')

    get_current_version('Google\ Chrome.app')
    print get_current_version('Google\ Chrome.app')

    print compare_versions('Google Chrome', 'Google\ Chrome.app')


main()
```

Here output:

```
80.0.3987.149
80.0.3987.149

False
```

I checked len and found that the it is not the same:

```
80.0.3987.149
13
80.0.3987.149

14
False
```

Before editing I had following value:

```
u'80.0.3987.149'
16
80.0.3987.149

14
False
```

I don't understand why I receive false???
Can you tell me what the problem?

Comment: Can you check if both outputs are the same `type`? And `length`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what if you change `compare_versions` to be:

```
def compare_versions(browser_name, app_path):
    if str(get_last_version(browser_name)) == str(get_current_version(app_path)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

If it solves your problem, the types of the versions are not the same.
If it doesn't work, try to print the `len` of the versions, maybe there is an hidden space or something like that...

In addition, try to `list(version1)` and `list(version2)` - it would split your string to list of chars and you will be able to find the diff more easily...

Comment: False. And I checked for FF, with the same result.

Comment: and what about the len of the versions, are they the same? try to print the types and the len of each of the versions...

Comment: Types both str. Length not the same, 13 for first def and 14 for second. What may it be?

Comment: you should find the character from 2 second func which is missing in the second. Try to run `list(version1)` and `list(version2)`. what is the diff? It will split both versions to list of chars and you will be able to find the diff easily

Comment: Edited the description.

Comment: @Vladimir, so what is the diff?

Comment: \n in the end of the second str.
You were right! Hidden symbol

Comment: happy to help :)